# Movement of protons during ETC

Tags: cellular-respiration

I don't understand why protons don't move from intermembrane space into the cytoplasm during chemiosmotic synthesis of ATP.

Technically they should because their concentration is also lower in the cytoplasm and the outer mitochondrial membrane is freely permeable.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide references for the various claims in your question: protons don't move to the cytoplasm, concentration is lower in the cytoplasm, mitochondrial membrane is freely permeable. This will help to identify where specifically you are having a question.